# Unable to return/process JSON in JQuery $.get()

Tags: jquery, json

I have a problem returning/processing JSON data while calling $.get() function. Here's the code:
JQuery:

```
$.get("script.php?",
        function(data) {
            if (data.status) {
                alert('ok');
            } else {
                alert(data.error);
            }               
    },'json');
```

PHP

```
if ($r) {
    $ret = array("status"=>true);
} else {
    $ret = array("status"=>false,"error"=>$error);
}
echo json_encode( $ret );
```

So this is the code. But the response is always taken as string in the jquery. data.status and data.error is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jQuery 1.4.x, otherwise you have to parse the returned data by yourself.

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: thanks! I'll have to dwnld the latest jquey to make things easier

Answer (score 4):

Your PHP script needs to set the `Content-type` header of the response to `application/json`, e.g.:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

Alternately, you can tell jQuery that's going to get JSON back by using the `dataType` option. Or just use [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), which does exactly that. :-)

**Edit** Sorry, just noticed: You **are** passing the `dataType` parameter to `get`. My suggestion is to look carefully at the response text: Is it really valid JSON? ([This site](http://www.jsonlint.com/) can help there.) From your quoted PHP it seems like it *should* be, but if there were any other output before or after...