# Getting data via JSON using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a website, where once a button is clicked it will trigger some javascript actions. I want to get some data via a php script i have written. I am using this method:

```
$.get("get_uni_info.php?addressToSearch=" + address, address, function(myData)
{
    $.each(myData, function(key, value) 
    {
        console.info(value);
    })
}, "json");
```

Inside the php code I am trying to get the value "address" to be able to search my database and send back some data but everything I just get nothing returned. I have test to the php code and it will return data if artificial measures are put in place so I can tell its not my PHP code.

Am i going wrong in my jQuery?

Comment: What does `console.log( myData )` say?

Comment: Maybe a duplication of [Unable to return/process JSON in JQuery $.get()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787325/unable-to-return-process-json-in-jquery-get) ?

Comment: FWIW, make certain that the data returned by the PHP code is valid JSON. I had a similiar problem some time back in that using getJSON I simply got nothing back without any error message. It turned out to be invalid JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the problem is in usage of `$.get` method.

You should write either

```
$.get("get_uni_info.php?addressToSearch=" + address, function(myData) {
    ...
}, "json");
```

or

```
$.get("get_uni_info.php", { addressToSearch : address }, function(myData) {
    ...
}, "json");
```

PHP code should handle `address` as:

```
$address = $_GET['addressToSearch'];
```

**EDIT:** If this does not help, we need to have a look at your PHP code (the response part precisely) to know where is the exact problem.

Comment: I used the {} method and its worked a treat for this and other JSON requests i've made thanks